# d language thread

Tags: d, dmd

How to properly pass a handle using `core.thread` in D? I have tried to do it like this, but the handle will change and I don't know why:

```
void WorkerThread(handle hand) 
{
    …
}

…

auto worker = new Thread( { WorkerThread( m_handle ); } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Thread` constructor can take a delegate that can have context. In the code shown, the context is the enclosing function. If that is a problem for some reason you should be able to do something like this:

```
void StartThread(handle hand) {
  struct Con {
    handle m_handle;
    void Go() { WorkerThread( m_handle ); }
  }

  Con con = new Con;
  con.m_handle = hand;
  auto worker = new Thread( &con.Go );
}
```